# "Share" button in Preview (10.9.5)

Tags: preview, sharing

I have tried to send pdfs via email from Preview but the app is not letting me.  The share button only gives me the option to send via "message" and "airdrop". I want to be able to send via Mac Mail and Outlook. What can I do to add these options under the "share" button.[image] [image]

Thanks
Brandi

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to reset your Preview app by deleting following files in your ~/Library.

Copy the stuff in brackets in to Finders "Go to Folder" window to find the files.

```
Caches/com.apple.Preview

Containers/com.apple.Preview
```

(~/Library/Containers)

```
Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist
```

(~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist)

```
Preferences/com.apple.Preview.SandboxedPersistentURLs.LSSharedFileList.plist
```

(~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.SandboxedPersistentURLs.LSSharedFileList.plist)

```
Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState
```

Launch the application and test.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Mail --> Preferences --> General, and select "Mail" as default reader. The mail application will now start to appear in preview and all the other apps.

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab > Services item (on the left). On the right side, under the "Messages" heading, ensure both items that start with "New Email" are checked.

(Specifically for OS X 10.10) Also, go to System Preferences > Extensions > Share Menu and ensure that there is an option named Mail and it is checked.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying.  I Went to Services and clicked both items that started with "New Email" (they weren't checked) but....still not giving me the option to share in Preview.  Would it help to know that i've always been able to share and then one day the option just disappeared?

Comment: @tubedogg What if you do not have an option for mail in the extensions/Share menu? ignore this. I was wrong. Sorry...